# Dynamic Indexing Google appengine

Tags: java, python, google-app-engine, indexing

My application creates and publishes data to its kinds, basically it makes a web service call to our PAAS application, and from the response creates these kinds and populates them.

So the issue is how to create a dynamic index because in this case, it does not use app cfg.py (actually would not because it is written in java and already deployed (w. Maven).

I found a solution that was posted on line however, that is using python, so my thought was to host a python application whose only purpose was to create the index.

The above mentioned solution however does not work for me. It returns a "A required header is missing", when I try to connect from the python app, or the url is not found if I try to connect in java. Note that I use SACSID in the python version, OAuth in the java version.

I cannot find the api documented online, and when I try to ask the author of the post, the post never goes through.

Please see this: does it look correct to you? And is that api still available?

http://rahulswackyworld.blogspot.com/2010/03/dynamic-indexes-with-google-app-engine.html

My code. Note I made a couple of changes to use UrlFetch

```
 from google.appengine.api import users

 from google.appengine.tools import appengine_rpc

 import webapp2

 import urllib

 from google.appengine.api import urlfetch


 #START MY STUFF

 class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        host = 'appengine.google.com'
        source = 'iristest-publicview.appspot.com'

        def auth_function():
            return ('<A valid admin username>','<A valid password')

        rpc_server = appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer(host, auth_function, 'Python 2.7', source)

        #Authenticate
        rpc_server._Authenticate();

        if rpc_server.authenticated == True:
            print 'Your Authentication Was Successful.'

            for cookie in rpc_server.cookie_jar:
                if cookie.name and cookie.name == 'SACSID':
                    print 'Authentication Token Obtained (%s => %s)' % (cookie.name, cookie.value)

        #index_payload is description of your indexes in YAML - This can be generated in various different ways.
        form_fields = '{ indexes:\n kind:< THE KIND I JUST CREATED DYNAMICALLY > \n properties: \n - name:extId \n direction:asc&app_id=< MY APP'S ID >&version=6 }'

        form_data = urllib.quote_plus(form_fields)

        url = 'https://appengine.google.com/api/datastore/index/add'

        result = urlfetch.fetch(url=url,
            payload=form_data,
            method=urlfetch.POST,
            headers={'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Cookie': cookie.value, 'Timeout': 60000, 'X-Same-Domain': '1' })

        print result.content

        print 'Uploading Index Successful'

        #END MY STUFF

    application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainPage),
    ], debug=True)
```

**